# Write in a file specified info Tkinter Python 2.7

Tags: python, file, tkinter

I would like to write in a file which has the name formed of two variables declared in other classes.

Example: my file should be written in the following directory: $HOME/nameoftheproject/clouds.yml
Home is defined in another class as:

```
def create_dir(self):
    home=expanduser("~")
```

nameoftheproject was defined in another class as an entry:

```
self.projectnamevar=tk.StringVar()
projectname=tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.projectnamevar)
projectname.pack()
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.container = container
        self.current_frame = None

        self.num_networks = tk.IntVar()  # Var shared between pages
        self.projectnamevar = tk.IntVar()
        self.num_tenants = tk.IntVar()
        self.home = tk.IntVar()
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        """Show a frame for the given page name"""
        if self.current_frame:
            self.current_frame.destroy()
            self.current_frame = None

        frame_class = globals()[page_name]  
        frame = frame_class(parent=self.container, controller=self)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frame.tkraise()
        self.current_frame = frame

class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Insert the name of your project",font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.projectnamevar=tk.StringVar()
        projectname=tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.projectnamevar)
        projectname.pack()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Create the directory", command=self.create_dir)
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Specify the number of tenants", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageFive"))
        button2.pack()

    def create_dir(self):
        home=expanduser("~")
        path1=home+"/"+self.projectnamevar.get()+"/"+self.projectnamevar.get()+"/variables/"
        path2=home+"/"+self.projectnamevar.get()+"/"+self.projectnamevar.get()+"/tasks/"
        os.makedirs(path1)
        os.makedirs(path2)

class PageFour(tk.Frame):

    def getclouds(self): 
        homepath=self.controller.home.get()
        projectpath=self.controller.projectnamevar.get()     
        with open("{}/{}/clouds.yml".format(homepath,projectpath), "w") as f:
           f.write("--- #" + "\n")
           f.write("clouds:" + "\n")
           for tenantname in self.entry_vars:
              f.write("   "+tenantname.get()+":"+ "\n")
              f.write("    auth:"+"\n")
              f.write("      auth_url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/v3/"+"\n")
              f.write("      username: admin"+"\n")
              f.write("      password: bad8462d0f904e79"+"\n")
              f.write("      project_name:"+tenantname.get()+"\n")
              f.write("      user_domain_name: Default"+"\n")
              f.write("      project_domain_name: Default")

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self,text="Define the tenants",font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        self.entries = []
        self.entry_vars = []

        for t in range(1, self.controller.num_tenants.get()+1):
            tenantname = tk.StringVar()
            tenant = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=tenantname)
            self.entry_vars.append(tenantname)
            self.entries.append(tenant)
            tenant.pack()
        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="Go to the start page",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"),)
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Create the clouds.yml", command=self.getclouds)
        button2.pack()
```

The error looks like:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "program.py", line 135, in getclouds
    with open("{}/{}/clouds.yml".format(homepath,projectpath), "w") as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0/0/clouds.yml'
```

The print of home path and project name looks like it's nothing fetched. 
Any idea how can be fixed this problem?

Comment: You are returning the IntVar and not getting its value. You need to use `homepath = self.controller.home.get()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'str'` is telling you that you are using an unsupported operand type or types. This would be because you are trying to concatenate an `instance` and a `string`. This is not possible and there is a simple fix.

Change:

```
homepath = self.controller.home
```

To:

```
homepath = self.controller.home.get()
```

That said you should not use `+` to combine strings in Python as it is deprecated. Instead the correct preferred method is using `format()`.

So instead of doing this:

```
homepath+"/"+projectpath+"/clouds.yml"
```

Do this:

```
"{}/{}/clouds.yml".format(homepath, projectpath)
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but I am still getting an error. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Albert From what I can see is your values are not getting pulled. Are you sure you have something set in the IntVar. Also I am not 100% sure you can set a directory to a number. What OS are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggestion. I am still getting the error that is in the question. The script has to run on Ubuntu and CentOS7. Prior to the error, I am successfully creating the directory, inserting the name of the tenants and after I am pressing the Create the clouds.yml button, I am getting that error from the question. Any idea what can be?